# Windows 8 apps - simple animation when button is clicked?

Tags: animation, button, windows-8

so I'm putting 2 same-sized StackPanels in the same position. The Visibility of the first StackPanel is Visible, while the second is Collapsed. Then I add this code to my button:

```
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         StackPanel1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
         StackPanel2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

this simply makes the first StackPanel gone and the second to be visible.

However, I would like to add a simple animation that will make the first StackPanel fade off to the left to disappear and the second StackPanel comes to alive from the right. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835017/windows-8-metro-app-animating-a-stack-panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this [MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh452701%28v=win.10%29.aspx) about animations. the animation you're looking for is the fade in/out animation.
You'll find the code of the [fade in animation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.fadeinthemeanimation.aspx)