# Add animations to controls in visual studio express for desktop 2012 c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

i'm doing an application with the new Visual Studio Express for Desktop 2012 (C#)
And i'm wondering if it is possible to add little animations to all the controls like it happens in Zune or in the apps for windows 8.
I dont know if you understood me, but try to use a windows 8 application or zune and you'll immediatly understand me. Thanks all and sorry for my english :/

Comment: Look at MSDN, there are lots of documentation and examples for animations and other styling.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156135/windows-8-apps-simple-animation-when-button-is-clicked) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible.

One simple option would be to use a set of 3rd party styles which already takes care of restyling the controls for you.  For example, [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) provides styles and many custom WPF controls which allow you to write desktop applications with a similar look and feel to Windows 8 Store applications.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify any UI framework, I assume you're using winforms, because you don't know any other UI frameworks actually exist (otherwise you wouldn't be using winforms to begin with).

If this is correct, then NO. winforms doesn't support `animations`, `gradients`, `rich media content`, or anything else that might look good. (read "support" as in: can be done without resorting to a bunch of horrible hacks).

If you're doing applications for Windows 8, I suggest you research about WinRT applications done in C# and XAML. Otherwise if you are doing desktop apps for versions of Windows prior to Windows 8, you may choose to do WPF applications in C# and XAML.